# Is Node.js ready for primetime?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, node.js

I'm getting ready to develop a website from scratch.  That site needs to have member authentication, db calls and realtime db communication.

Is Node.js ready for primetime or will I lose time if I do the entire site in node?

I'm coming from PHP using CodeIgniter and MySQL.

Comment: and belongs on programmers even if it were rephrased...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925414/is-node-js-ready-for-production-use

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node

Comment: If A) Your website is not critical, B) Your willing to do maintenance and C) you know _javascript_ then by all means use node.